# Slow SQL Connection

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2012-express

I am running an ASP classic website on a new dedicated server with SQL Server 2012 on it. All is running nicely but the database connection takes about 5.1 seconds to establish when a page is loaded. If the page is refreshed the connection is instant (presumably due to connection pooling?) but if the page is reloaded a few minutes later the connection takes 5.1 seconds to establish again.

Are there any settings that I can change to speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pinning your tables to memory on the SQL side?

Check in chrome, most likely under the network tab, you will find your timeout is due to what Chrome Networking Tools defines as "waiting" - which means the browser is waiting for a response.

http://www.mcobject.com/in_memory_database

and you could try the DBCC PINTABLE function, so that the query doesn't have to fire from a non-cached engine each time.